# Update String Array with Subsequent Update of ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to update a String in a `ListView`, and have the update be reflected in the `ListView`.  Here are the basics of what's going on:

```
testStrings = {"String", "String", String"};
ListView l = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView1 );
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testStrings);
l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Later, `testStrings` is update like so:

```
testStrings[1] = "new string";
```

Note, just the text is changing, not the cardinality of the String array.

On a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3, the text in the `ListView` is updated as expected, with no additional calls to the adapter.

On a Google Nexus 7 running Android 4.4.2, nothing happens.  On the Nexus 7, I've tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the adapter, and that doesn't do anything either.

I've seen a number of questions about `ListView`s not updating, but those examples seem to be doing something more complicated than what I'm trying to do.  Why is one device working fine, but not the other?  How do I get the `ListView` on the Nexus 7 updating correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to be more direct about modifying the adapter. When I walk through the Android code that constructs ArrayAdapter using a String array, it first makes an ArrayList from your String[], and then makes the ArrayAdapter from the ArrayList. While the source does seem to point to the ArrayList and then the array, it does seem a risky proposition to expect ArrayAdapter to be aware that you have modified the String[] deep inside it. It is interesting that calling notifyDataSetChanged works on one device and not another. But I think a much better approach is to remove and then add the strings from the adapter. This way the adapter will know that something is happening to it.

```
adapter.remove(adapter.get(1));
adapter.insert("new string", 1);
```

Comment: Hi Bruce - actually, I don't even bother calling .notifyDataSetChanged on the first devices.  I just update the string array, and everything else happens automatically.  The functionality has been consistent across all of the test phones I have (a variety of Android versions), as well as the emulators I've tried, just not on the Nexus 7.